# Configuring spring PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer and environment via XML

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to upgrade the libraries of some of our older apps and part of that is moving from spring 3 to spring 4.1.6.  I have what I believe is a pretty typical configuration using Maven to pull in dependencies and then using maven profiles and filtering to choose the correct properties files to run the app with. Looks something like this.

```
pom.xml

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <app.env>Development</app.env>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <webResource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            </webResource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

My spring application context sits in the filtered resource directory with the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean definition.  ${app.env} gets filtered out to load by Development.properties file

```
ApplicaitonContext.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:com/tms/edu/settings/${app.env}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My understanding at this point is that when using ProperySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer as opposed to the older PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer that it's supposed to automatically register the resources as a PropertySource so that an autowired Environment object can simply call getProperty("db.location") and have that available at runtime. So I should be able to have a simple class in my scanned package that essentially do this:

```
@Service
public class PropertyReader {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getPropertyValue(String key) {
        return env.getProperty(urlkey);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work however.  getProperty() returns null for a key that should work and inspecting the environment object in the debugger I don't see my resources loaded in the list of propertySources.

I only am finding examples of how to configure PropertySource with annotations but that isn't going to work with how we manage profiles and properties in our maven builds. I know I could use @Value ${} style annotaiton to grab these values and that works fine. But I'm still curious as to why Environment isn't working as I'd expect.

Comment: same problem, i've tried everything. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: It's been a while so this might not be satisfactory, but looking through the code it looks like I got it to work in one project, but the configuration seems to be the same as what I described in my question.  Other projects I used 
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
and just hard coded in a single property file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XML configuration have you tried add `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />` or 
  `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${app.env}.properties"/>` ?

It's the equivalent of `@PropertySource("classpath:whatever.properties")`

This namespace enables PropertySources, see [here on "Using the @Value annotation"](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

Note: `classpath` can refer directly to `resources` folder which is the normal place to put your properties as a Maven project

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried that.  But I seem to be getting the same outcome this way.
I have a breakpoint in the spring PropertiesLoader class and I can see it finding and loading my resource using the PropertiesLoaderUtils.

I get the logger output:2015-Apr-27 11:38:44,112  INFO PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [com/tms/edu/settings/SystemTest.properties]

But once it gets to env.getProperties(key) it returns null.

Comment: Strange, `Environment` is not nul ? Spring recognize your file, your property is correct and the value in it is right? I already had that kind of problem but was one of the reasons, or just need a clean build.

Comment: Environment gets autowired "correctly" (minus expected properties).   Interestingly enough I tried to grab the applicationContext by implementing ApplicationContextAware, I included the bean definition in my xml but setApplicationContext() wasn't being called unless I explicitly Autowired the bean.  It's like I have the behavior of a lazy loaded context but I'm never setting that.  There's some weird deeper config issue going on I think.